# Algorithm and datastructure suggestion for Activity planning based on several factors

Tags: algorithm

I have been trying to find the right algorithm and data structure to plan activities for the given number of days. The events have multiple datapoints associated with them. I need the most number of activities someone can do for the given days.

Data points for **Activity**:

1. Duration of the activity takes to perform
2. Timeframe the activity can be done (e.g. 9am-5pm)
3. Proximity of the events to each other (e.g event 1 could be at point A, event 2 preferably should be near to it and so on)
4. Highest rated activity should be done first

I looked at [activity selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem) but not sure if this may not fit into what I am looking at.

Comment: What are you trying to maximize?

Comment: I am trying to maximize the number of activities per day

Comment: Unless you replace "should" with **must**  in your problem description the problem is ambiguous because you haven't described how to resolve conflicting criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Let `G(V, E)` be the directed, acyclic graph (DAG) defined in this way:

- there is a vertex `v` in `V` for each activity
- there are also two special vertexes v_start and v_target in V
- there is an edge `(i, j)` in `E` for each pair of activities `i` and `j` such that `i` ends before `j` and are "compatible" according to your proximity criterion
- for each vertex in V different from v_start and v_end, edges `(v_start, v)` and `(v, v_end)` are in E (that is, `v_start` has an outgoing edge for every activity and `v_end` has an incoming edge for every activity)

Then what you want is the longest path from source to destination, which can be done in linear time by following the simple algorithm outlined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#Acyclic_graphs_and_critical_paths).